Fish tank fishes
Can anyone share the names of common "fish tank" fish that are also kosher?
Can someone share a link of where I might find the names if you yourself dont know the names?
I know goldfish for one.

Carp is also a common kosher fishtank fish

@Moishe Goldfish is a kind of carp


Whitefish
Angelfish

People in this video put them in a fish tank:
Here it says that they are both kosher
I suggest looking at this big list of kosher fish and seeing which ones you can put in a fish tank.
Hope this helped

if you have a big enough tank, any fish can be a fish tank fish

That is true, I assumed he was talking about a normal sized fish tank
